# Looking for open dataset containing vacation / annual leave data for counties of the European Union?

Tags: data-request, economics, europe

I am looking for a preferably open dataset that contains information regarding the dates that that employees took days off their annual leave for the countries of the EU. Is there any similar information available for other countries anyone is aware of?

To avoid misunderstanding: I'm *not* looking for public holiday dates themselves.

Comment: It's possible that a government agency might have such data that they'd be willing to make available in aggregate (so you could see what months of the year people are more likely to take off in).  Of course, that might mask sick days vs. planned vacations unless they broke that out.  The only other thing that I'm aware of are various charts showing minimum required annual leave by country.  Eg, see https://cepr.net/documents/no-vacation-update-2014-04.pdf .  I've also seen other reports showing that Americans are less likely than workers from other countries to use their vacation time.

Answer (score 1):

[here's the official holidays calendar for France until 2018](http://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/?sort=modified&refine.features=calendar) as Open Data.

Cheers
Nicolas